# ColdFusion and PHP variables

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am looking to port some application code from PHP to ColdFusion

ColdFusion Variables:

```
variables.*
request.*
session.*
application.*
server.*
form.*
url.*
arguments.*
```

PHP variables

```
$something

$_POST['something']
$_GET['something']

function getSomething($something){   
global $someglobal;
$something
...
```

Comment: If you're porting _from_ PHP then this question is backwards. :/

Comment: I know ColdFusion, but not PHP

Comment: Precisely, so you should identify what PHP scopes the application uses, determine what they do, and then you'll know what CF equivalents they map to. If you get stuck with any part of that, you can ask a specific question (potentially with relevant code to give context of where its being used and if that use is ideal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the available scopes in ColdFusion with their appropriate PHP counterpart to the right:

If you use a variable name without a scope prefix, ColdFusion checks the scopes in the following order to find the variable:

> Local (function-local, UDFs and CFCs only) => No array.
>
> Arguments => ?
>
> Thread local (inside threads only) Query (not a true scope; variables in query loops) => ?
>
> Thread => ?
>
> Variables => $GLOBALS[]
>
> CGI => $_SERVER[]
>
> Cffile => $_FILES[]
>
> URL => $_GET[]
>
> Form => $_POST[]
>
> Cookie => $_COOKIE[]
>
> Client => ?
>
> Request => $_REQUEST[]

Here are the pages where I would use to reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't do ColdFusion, but I can hazard some guesses based on [this documentation](http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_variable_types.cfm).

For starters, PHP doesn't classify its variables explicitly by scope.

```
variables.*
```

...is just `$var1` or `$foo` or whatever.  It's scoped depending on its location - is it in a function, a class, free, etc.

```
request.*
```

These are apparently "non-persistent global variables" which are probably `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]` (both arrays) in PHP.

```
session.*
```

That's an easy one.  `$_SESSION`.

```
application.*
```

This is probably best approximated by [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

On that page are several other variable types that will probably answer your question.  Be wary, though, in PHP global variables are a quick invitation to security holes.

Comment: You got Request and Application wrong. `$_GET` maps to `Url`, `$_POST` maps to `Form`, `$_SERVER` maps to `Cgi` (all three of these are per-request scopes populated with relevant vars automatically.)

Comment: Request is just a generic global/per-request scope, not pre-populated (except by some frameworks). (Variables is per-request in templates, but persistent in objects, which can themselves be persisted in Session/Application/Server scopes)

Comment: Application is a persistent scope shared by all scripts with the same application name.

Comment: (There's also Server which is not like PHP's Server, but a bit like PHP's phpinfo() function (contains server/java/OS/etc version info), as well as being able to persist objects for the lifetime of the server.)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I don't do CF...why don't you answer this?  You're obviously better informed than myself ;)

Comment: Well I was only intending a quick single comment, then a whole stream dropped out. :S I think the better solution is for the OP to spend a bit of time learning PHP (which they'll need to do to anyway to convert a whole application), and then this stuff wont be an issue.

Comment: Ahh, flushed the buffer, makes sense :)  Well anyway it's odd mine is the only answer here!